# Why iOS doesn't play audio of video?

Tags: ios, open-source

I wrote an Android application and in that, I used the following command to mix audio and video via ffmpeg(video.mp4 doesn't have audio):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -codec copy result.mp4
```

An Android devices there is no problem and videos are playing with audio, but on iOS, videos just play without any sound.

What could be the problem?